# Best methods to get image file size

Tags: php

I want to start a discussion about getting file size of image in two cases.

If we have two scenarios:

1. www.example.com/test.jpg)

in a first we have direct link to the image and in a second

2. www.example.com/getImage?id=3

In a both cases we are getting the same image.

What is best to use?

I tried to use those two methods:
        $url ="www.example.com/test.jpg";

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $size;
```

and second one which is much simpler:

```
$length = get_headers($url,true);
print_r($length['Content-Length']);
```

What are benefits of a first compared with a second?

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same. Read the php manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

`CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD - content-length of download, read from Content-Length: field`

So, basically `CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD` gets the data from the `Content-Length` header itself. But, the 2nd method is unhandled for exceptions and can give you an undefined index and it must be handled as some servers do not provide Content-Length in the header.